# Can a active directory group be administered by itself?

Tags: active-directory

I was wondering if an active directory group can be administered by itself.

Unfortunately I have no access to an active directory setup -as administrator- to do the test by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just add the group as it's manager.

[image]

Make sure the user who is in this group logs out and in again, so the group memberships are applied properly. Afterwards he is able to manage the group with the normal management tools.

```powershell
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (Get-ADGroup test)  -Members (Get-ADUser otheruser)
```